# latex date: month-year only

Tags: templates, date

In my thesis class file, I currently have

```
\begin{center}%
\@date%
\end{center}%
```

Which generates a date in the format day-month-year on the title page.

How do I change this so it only states the month and year?

Thank you

Comment: `\the\month-\the\year`

Comment: so i would have :

\begin{center}%
\@date\the\month-\the-year%
\end{center}%

or something different?

Comment: @dragoness24 No, that would display the date as stored in `\@date` followed by the month and year. Either redefine `\@date` to initialise the date to `\the\month\-the\year` or replace `\@date` with `\the\month-\the\year`. It depends if you want to allow the use of `\date` in the document to override the default date.

Comment: okay i see :) i tried this, but it came up as 3-2018. Is there a way to make it say March 2018?

Comment: All answers assume something, nobody knows what is going on.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear. A class file should never be changed. What you should do is `\date{Wombat}` to *hopefully* get Wombat as the date. Who knows.

Comment: @Johannes_B This is true. I was assuming that the OP was creating their own custom class file (based on the "my thesis class file" part rather than identifying a specific class).

Answer (score 7):

> Which generates a date in the format day-month-year on the title page.

`\@date` is usually initialised to `\today` and the default format of `\today` is the US style *month* *day*, *year* as illustrated in the simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image: March 11, 2018]

If your document is producing day-month-year for the default definition of `\@date` (`\today`), then you've likely loaded a package that alters `\today`, such as a language package (`babel` or `polyglossia`) or one of the [date packages](https://ctan.org/topic/date-time). The solution depends on which package you've loaded that's redefined `\today`. If it's just `babel` or `polyglossia`, then you can use [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) with [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english). (Both need installing independently.)

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showdayofmonth=false}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

[image: March 2018]

There are various other regions supported by `datetime2-english`. Choose the most applicable. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-US]{showdayofmonth=false}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[en-IE]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-IE]{showdayofmonth=false}

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

The other possibility is that `\@date` has been redefined (so that it no longer expands to `\today`). Check your class file and document code for any instance of `\date` or any explicit definition of `\@date`. You can use `\show` for debugging. For example, if you (temporarily) modify the code to

```
\begin{center}%
\show\@date
\@date
\end{center}%
```

Then the transcript will show the definition of `\@date`. If you get the message

```
> \@date=macro:
->\today .
```

Then it's `\today` that has been modified, but if you get something different, for example

```
> \@date=macro:
->11 March 2018.
```

then `\@date` has been redefined, in which case you need to find where it's been redefined and modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see "March 2018" in your thesis; simply enter `\date{March 2018}` in the text of your thesis.  This will initialize macro `\@date` to `March 2018`.

Besides, here a simple macro (`\printdate`) to print the date in the desired format:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\printdate}{%
   \ifcase \month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or
    August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi \space \number\year}

\begin{document}

\printdate

\end{document}
```