# Hebrew date without day of month using polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, datetime2

I'd like to typeset today's month and year, where "today" is determined automatically. However, I'd like to do so using polyglossia's Hebrew locale. I've tried to adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419608/21685) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[he]{showdayofmonth=false}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

However, this prints the day of the month (I used `XeLaTeX`):

[image: Hebrew date with day-of-month]

Instead of the desired:

[image: Hebrew date without day-of-monty]

* The package `datetime2-hebrew` is installed in my TeX installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple things are intertwining.

With the current code setup, `datetime2` is ignoring the option:

```
Package datetime2 Warning: Region `he' has ignored 
(datetime2)                the following settings:
(datetime2)                showdayofmonth=false
```

and `polyglossia` is calculating the date via `hebrewcal.sty` where the output routine hard-codes the day number using a formatting command defined as:

```
\def\@FormatForHebrew#1#2#3{%
  \Hebrewnumeral{#1}~ב\HebrewMonthName{#2}{#3}~%
  \HebrewYearName{#3}}
```

To fix that, as a workaround, put the following code in the preamble, before `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@FormatForHebrew#1#2#3{%
  \HebrewMonthName{#2}{#3}~%
  \HebrewYearName{#3}}
\makeatother
```

so that `\today` produces this:

[image: month year]

Alternatively, to restrict the redefinition to a particular instance only, use braces `{` `}` and put the code in the body of the document with the `\today` command, such that

```
\today

{
\makeatletter
\def\@FormatForHebrew#1#2#3{%
  \HebrewMonthName{#2}{#3}~%
  \HebrewYearName{#3}}
\makeatother
\today
}

\today
```

produces this:

[image: braced code]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[he]{showdayofmonth=false}

%%for global change:
%\makeatletter
%\def\@FormatForHebrew#1#2#3{%
%  \HebrewMonthName{#2}{#3}~%
%  \HebrewYearName{#3}}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\today

{
\makeatletter
\def\@FormatForHebrew#1#2#3{%
  \HebrewMonthName{#2}{#3}~%
  \HebrewYearName{#3}}
\makeatother
\today
}

\today
\end{document}
```

A longer-term solution will require deeper investigation, particularly as multi-way package interactions are involved.

Comment: Thaank you! Would you consider this a bug? Should I report it? If so, to which package should I address the bug report?

Comment: Good question. It's an unintended result of independent packages interacting. Probably a feature request for `polyglossia`; `datetime2-hebrew.ldf` is assuming either `\hebrewdate` or `\hebdate` (I'm guessing one is `polyglossia` and one is `babel`) and `datetime2` also issues the message about the option setting, so it looks like `datetime2` is downstream.

Comment: Could you elaborate please: what feature should I request from `polyglossia`'s developers? In what way should they modify `\hebrewdate`?

Comment: So that there is an option so that `\today` prints month and year, without the day. As in your question.

Comment: It might be a useful long-term outcome if someone writes a standalone `calendars` package, rather than there being individual adhoc calculations going on in this package or that package.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a simpler solution.

(See also [format the year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610789/161015))

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}


\newcommand{\ToNoDay}{% just month and year
 \hebrewsetreg\HebrewMonthName{\hebrewmonth}{\hebrewday}~\HebrewYearName{\hebrewyear}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{english} 
\bigskip \hfill TODAY 
\end{english}

\today
    
\begin{english} 
\bigskip    \hfill  MONTH
\end{english}   
    
\HebrewMonthName{\hebrewmonth}{\hebrewday} % It needs \today to be run earlier

\begin{english} 
    \bigskip    \hfill  YEAR
\end{english}   

\HebrewYearName{\hebrewyear} % It needs \today to be run earlier
    
\begin{english} 
\bigskip    \hfill  MONTH YEAR
\end{english}   

\ToNoDay % date without the day     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain the benefit of this solution over @cicada's?

Comment: @einpoklum It does not produce the warning and in my (sporadic) use the macros are easier to remember.

Comment: Ok, but - I would add this information to the answer, as it's not immediately clear why it's "simple".

Comment: @einpoklum simpler to understand and apply. No TeX, no hacks.  Adjectives with qualifiers always carry bias.