# How to format today's year per the Hebrew calendar with polyglossia?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew

The following piece of code typesets today's date according to the Hebrew calendar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

When compiled with `XeLaTeX`, this code produced:

[image: Full Hebrew date]

The part of this line that represents the year is [image: Hebrew year]. There are other formats for the Hebrew year that are in common use:

- Without the apostrophe: [image: Hebrew year without apostrophe after the initial letter]. This format is used e.g. by [ynet](https://www.ynet.co.il/home/0,7340,L-8,00.html):

[image: Ynet Hebrew date format]

- Without the initial letter as well as the following apostrophe: [image: Hebrew date without the first letter]. This format is used e.g. by [Ha'aretz](https://www.haaretz.co.il/):

[image: Ha'aretz Hebrew date format]

How can I specify these alternative year formats? I'm particularly interested in the most succinct version, the one used by Ha'aretz.

Comment: One possibility is redefining `polyglossia`'s `hebrewcal.sty`'s `\HebrewYearName` macro. Another possibility is setting up a custom definition file (for `polyglossia`, or possibly `datetime2` maybe) with all the options. Alternatively, someone may know a simple and plain solution. Alternatively, a manual solution for a one-off or short-term use, but presumably you want an automatic convertor and don't want to code up your own `ifcase`-type statement (inspired by the js, or however those pages do it).

Comment: ynet just insert the date as text: `<span>ז&#x27; באלול התשפ&quot;א</span>`. So does ha'aretz: `<span class="atm hk atn ato atp atq atr ats nv hq hr">ז׳ אלול תשפ״א</span>`. So no calculation tips there.

Comment: @Cicada: If you could possibly come up with a solution in the same vein as your answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610612/21685) that'd be great.

Comment: @Cicada: An acceptable solution would be to assume that there is exactly one letter preceding the apostrophe, and therefore the two alternatives can be obtained by removing the first, respectively the first 2, characters of the year.

Comment: You could use a regex expression in expl3 syntax to do that.

Comment: @Cicada: Could you help me with it, please?

Comment: Had a quick look earlier: regex on text or expandable macros is easy, but `\today` is a calculation (starting with `datetime2`), and I haven't been able to get it to fully expand to the final text (yet).So perhaps it should be a separate question.  Where does ynet etc get the text from? For the immediate goal, typing what you want manually is not an option, I'm guessing?

Comment: You wrote: "perhaps it should be a separate question". I'll gladlly ask a new question, but I don't quite understand what it is that I need to ask.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. I expanded the answer to cover other formats for the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is exclusively based on `hebrewcal.sty` (Hebrew calendar for polyglossia).

The current hebrew year is 5781. The abbreviated format (as used by Ha'aretz) is to quote only 781.

The code can deliver the full year or the short year format using the `fullyear` key.

In `hebrewcal.sty` the `fullyear` key is set to `false` by default, but the corresponding branch in the macro
`\HebrewYearName`  was not fully executed. (line #53 of `hebrewcal.sty)`. I added a `\relax` to correct the problem.

Tested with xelatex with Arial fonts and  lualatex with the New Computer Modern fonts.

[image: z1]

[image: h]

This is what a normal `\today` looked like:

[image: x1]

```
 %!TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
 %\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

\makeatletter   
\hebrewsetreg
\def\HebrewYearName#1{{%
        \@tempcnta=#1\divide\@tempcnta by 1000\multiply\@tempcnta by 1000
        \ifnum#1=\@tempcnta\relax % divisible by 1000: disambiguate
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}\ (לפ"ג)%
        \else % not divisible by 1000
        \ifnum#1<1000\relax     % first millennium: disambiguate
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}\ (לפ"ג)%
        \else%
        \ifnum#1<5000
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}%
        \else%
        \ifnum#1<6000 % current millenium, print without thousands
        \@tempcnta=#1\relax
        \if@hebrew@fullyear\else\advance\@tempcnta by -5000\relax\fi % changed <<<<<<
        \Hebrewnumeral{\@tempcnta}%
        \else % #1>6000
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}%
        \fi
        \fi
        \fi
        \fi}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\ThisHebrewMonth}{%
\HebrewMonthName{\hebrewmonth}{\hebrewday}
}

\newcommand{\ThisHebrewYear}{%
\HebrewYearName{\hebrewyear}
}

\newcommand{\ThisHebrewDay}{%
\Hebrewnumeral{\hebrewday}
}

\newcommand{\HaToday}{%
\ThisHebrewDay\ThisHebrewMonth\ThisHebrewYear
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{english}     
        \bigskip    \hfill This day  
    \end{english}   
    
    \ThisHebrewDay
    
    \begin{english}     
        \bigskip    \hfill This month    
    \end{english}
    
    \ThisHebrewMonth
    
    \begin{english}     
        \bigskip    \hfill This year    
    \end{english}   
    
    \ThisHebrewYear
    
    \begin{english} 
        \bigskip  \hfill Today,  Ha'aretz way   
    \end{english}   
    
    \HaToday
    
\end{document}
```

**Expanded answer**

To cover some of the common formats for the Hebrew year I added 2 keys:

(1) `fullyear = false/true`. True= displays the present millennium (5). False: suppress the 5, but display the millennium if it is less than 5000.

(default=false => `\setkeys{hebrew}{fullyear=false}`)

(2) `firstapos = false/true`. False= suppress the first apostrophe in a full year display.

(default=false => `\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=false}` )

The global  default is `\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=false, fullyear=false}`

Keys can be placed anywhere and will affect the document from that point onwards.

The macro `\HebrewYearName{<year>}` accepts a numeric value for a year or `\hebrewyear` the current year.

**Notes**

The macro `\@hebrew@@numeral` controlling the first apostrophe is from `babel-hebrewalph.def`

The macro `\HebrewYearName` controlling the full or short format is from `hebrewcal.sty`

[image: xx]

```
 %!TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
 %\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}   

\makeatletter   
\hebrewsetreg

\define@boolkey{hebrew}[@hebrew@]{firstapost}[true]{}
\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=false}

\renewcommand*{\@hebrew@@numeral}[1]{%{% first apostrophe, from babel-hebrewalph.def
    \ifnum#1<\z@\space\xpg@warning{Illegal value (#1) for Hebrew numeral}%
    \else
    \@tempcnta=#1\@tempcntb=#1\relax
    \divide\@tempcntb by 1000
    \ifnum\@tempcntb=0\gim@nomil\@tempcnta\relax
    \else%
    \if@hebrew@firstapost%  
    {\@gim@apostfalse\@gim@finalfalse\@hebrew@numeral\@tempcntb}׳% 
    \else%
    \@gim@aposttrue\@gim@finalfalse\@hebrew@numeral\@tempcntb\relax% <<<<<<<<<<<
    \fi
    \multiply\@tempcntb by 1000\relax
    \advance\@tempcnta by -\@tempcntb\relax
    \gim@nomil\@tempcnta\relax
    \fi
    \fi
}
    
\def\HebrewYearName#1{{%{% full or short format, from hebrewcal.sty
        \@tempcnta=#1\divide\@tempcnta by 1000\multiply\@tempcnta by 1000
        \ifnum#1=\@tempcnta\relax % divisible by 1000: disambiguate
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}\ (לפ"ג)%
        \else % not divisible by 1000
        \ifnum#1<1000\relax     % first millennium: disambiguate
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}\ (לפ"ג)%
        \else%
        \ifnum#1<5000
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}%
        \else%
        \ifnum#1<6000 % current millenium, print without thousands
        \@tempcnta=#1\relax
        \if@hebrew@fullyear\else\advance\@tempcnta by -5000\relax\fi % changed <<<<<<
        \Hebrewnumeral{\@tempcnta}%
        \else % #1>6000
        \Hebrewnumeral{#1}%
        \fi
        \fi
        \fi
        \fi}}   

\makeatother
    
\begin{document}    
        
\begin{english} 
    \bigskip  \hfill \small This year,  full format
\end{english}

\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=true, fullyear=true} 
\HebrewYearName{\hebrewyear} 

\begin{english} 
    \bigskip  \hfill \small 5781,  without apostrophe   
\end{english}

\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=false, fullyear=true} 
\HebrewYearName{5781} 

\begin{english} 
    \bigskip  \hfill \small Common usage (omitting thousands)
\end{english}

\setkeys{hebrew}{firstapost=false, fullyear=false} % default
\HebrewYearName{5781} \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted your answer, even though I don't understand your calculations and therefore can't verify that your code actually works as intended in all scenarios, but it works well today.

Comment: @Evan Aad I expanded on my previous answer by adding two keys to set the three required formats for the Hebrew year.

Comment: Thanks. This is great.